# Failure to import Corda Gradle project in IntelliJ

Tags: corda

When I open a Corda Gradle project in IntelliJ and click `Import Gradle project`, the project fails to import, and I get the following error messages:

> Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings
>
> Project JDK is not specified. Open Project SDK Configuration

What do I need to do to make the Gradle project import correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the project's SDK.

Click on `File` > `Project Structure...`, select the correct Java 8 JDK (1.8.0_131 or above), and click `Apply`.

Then import the Gradle project again. You will have to close and re-open the project to force the `Import Gradle project` dialog to re-appear.